# In Visual Studio Angular2 Template, what's the difference between boot.browser.ts vs boot.server.ts?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript

In Visual Studio Angular2 Template, what's the difference between 'boot.browser.ts' vs 'boot.server.ts'?

Both are self generated files under the ClientApp folder when you create an Angular Project in Visual Studio.

The 'boot.browser.ts' file seems to be the entry point, but what the heck is 'boot.server.ts'? Why do we need it?

I'm new to Angular2 and I'm having trouble getting my head around this.

Thanks!

Comment: boot.server.ts the server side entry point for asp-prerender-module. You can see the reference in in the Index.cshtml file in the Home controller. 

For a better understanding, read this page.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services

Comment: Thanks for the answer